# Django ORM Query: getting "has many" relation objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

There is a model:

```
class DomainPosition(models.Model):
    domain   = models.ForeignKey(Domain)
    keyword  = models.ForeignKey(Keyword)
    date     = models.DateField()
    position = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['domain', 'keyword']
```

How to get the positions records for a template if for each domain I want to display a next table (figures in the table are position values):

```
+----------+--------+--------+-------+--------
| keyword  | date1  | date2  | date3 | ...
+----------+--------+--------+-------+--------
| keyword1 |    2   |    6   |    7  |   ...
+----------+--------+--------+-------+--------
| keyword2 |    4   |   12   |    5  |   ...
+----------+--------+--------+-------+--------
| keyword3 |    6   |    3   |    9  |   ...
+----------+--------+--------+-------+--------
```

where `views.py`:

```
def show_domain_history(request, domain_name):
    domain = Domain.objects.filter(name__contains=domain_name)
    if not domain:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        # positions = ...
        variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'domain':    domain[0].name,
            'positions': positions,
        })
        return render_to_response('history.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def show_domain_history(request, domain_name):
    domain = Domain.objects.filter(name__contains=domain_name)
    if not domain:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        variables = {'domain': domain }
        return render_to_response('history.html', variables)
```

now in the template you can iterate through this as:

```
{% for dom in domain %}

name: {{ dom.name }}

{% for item in dom.domainposition_set %} 

     date: item.date

     position: item.position
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a foreign key from `DomainPosition` to `Domain`, you should be able to get the set of all domain positions that reference a particular domain `dom` with `dom.domainposition_set.all()`.

You can then build your table by iterating over this list of domain positions in your template.

Comment: And don't forget you don't need the brackets after `all` when you're in the template.